# What is missing in this soap request?

Tags: php, laravel, soap, soapui

I am trying to consume a SOAP API, here is the WSDL:http://clientes.tcc.com.co/servicios/informacionremesas.asmx?wsdl specifically the method called: ConsultarInformacionRemesasEstadosUEN

The problem is that when I make the request with a program called SoapUI I get the 200 response, but when I do it from my Laravel project I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
protected $pass ;
    protected $url;

    public function __construct($pass='APIKEY',$url="http://clientes.tcc.com.co/servicios/informacionremesas.asmx?wsdl")
    {
        $this->pass=$pass;
        $this->url=$url;
    }
    public function test()
    {
        try{
            $param=array('Clave'=>$this->pass,'numeroremesa'=>433654926,'unidadnegocio'=>1,'Respuesta'=>0);
            $client = new SoapClient($this->url,array('trace'=>TRUE));
            $response =$client->ConsultarInformacionRemesasEstadosUEN($param);
            dd($client->__getLastRequest());
            exit;
            // $array= json_decode(json_encode($response),true);
        }
        catch(Exeption $fault){
            return response()->json(['entro'=>'entro en la exepcion',"error"=>$fault->getMessage()],400);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following 500 error

```
"message": "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\n   at ServiciosWeb.InformacionRemesas.ConsultarInformacionRemesasEstadosUEN(String Clave, List`1 remesas, List`1& remesasrespuesta, Int32& Respuesta, String& Mensaje) in C:\\TCC\\Proyectos\\Legacy\\WSNET\\2-Desarrollo\\3-Servicios\\ServiciosWeb\\ServiciosWeb\\InformacionRemesas.asmx.vb:line 443\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---",
    "exception": "SoapFault",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GirosYa\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\ExternalApis\\TccController.php",
    "line": 35,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GirosYa\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\ExternalApis\\TccController.php",
            "line": 35,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "SoapClient",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

It works using SoapUI so I am not sure if that software is adding a header or something like that, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that WSDL and the error message, it looks like your `'numeroremesa'=>433654926,'unidadnegocio'=>1` needs to be wrapped in an array whose key in the main array is "remesas".  This means your `$param` should be as follows:

```
$param=array('Clave'=>$this->pass,'remesas' => array('numeroremesa'=>433654926,'unidadnegocio'=>1),'Respuesta'=>0)
```

The parts of the WSDL that indicate this are:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="remesas" type="tns:ArrayOfRemesaUEN"/>
```

...

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="RemesaUEN" nillable="true" type="tns:RemesaUEN"/>
```

...

```
<s:complexType name="RemesaUEN">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="numeroremesa" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="unidadnegocio" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

The part of the error message that indicates this is:

> at
>   ServiciosWeb.InformacionRemesas.ConsultarInformacionRemesasEstadosUEN(String
>   Clave, List`1 remesas, List`1& remesasrespuesta, Int32& Respuesta,
>   String& Mensaje)

Note the argument list shown for the function

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this was very helpfull, I am a newbie with SOAP :p.